# How to call socket super constructor?

Tags: java, sockets, constructor, superclass

Could you tell me if there is something wrong in this call to the upper class constructor?
Every time I try to create a new object with this constructor the application just crashes, I have checked and the parameters that I send are correct, but still crashing...

```
package com.example.bulbcontrol2;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ConnectionTool extends Socket
{   
    private PrintWriter outputData;
    private BufferedReader inputBuffer;
    private String message = null;

    public ConnectionTool(InetAddress host, int port) throws IOException 
    {   
        super(host,port);
        outputData = new PrintWriter(this.getOutputStream(), true);
        inputBuffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getInputStream()));
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
10-31 12:35:56.407: W/dalvikvm(9971): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41577700) 
10-31 12:35:56.407: E/AndroidRuntime(9971): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
10-31 12:35:56.407: E/AndroidRuntime(9971): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=open_connection flg=0x10 } in com.example.bulbcontrol2.AsyncConnection$1@41e3ee90 
10-31 12:35:56.407: E/AndroidRuntime(9971): at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:773)
```

Comment: Could you post the console output? What exception are you getting?

Comment: 10-31 12:35:56.407: W/dalvikvm(9971): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41577700)
10-31 12:35:56.407: E/AndroidRuntime(9971): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-31 12:35:56.407: E/AndroidRuntime(9971): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=open_connection flg=0x10 } in com.example.bulbcontrol2.AsyncConnection$1@41e3ee90
10-31 12:35:56.407: E/AndroidRuntime(9971):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:773)

Comment: Why not just use composition instead of inheritance?  Might want to check out *Effective Java* from Joshua Bloch.  http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/9780137150021/classes-and-interfaces/ch04lev1sec4

Comment: @Jebe In future, please edit your question rather than placing lots of data into a comment.

Comment: Instead of trying subclass Socket I suggest you wrap it as this is how it is usually used.

Comment: Sorry, probably the constructor is OK, but I was getting an android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException that I wasn´t catching, I will try to know why is this Exception showing when I am connecting from an AsyncTask.